# swiper loop mode when slides show all in a same view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, swiper.js

Swiper slider is not working what I expected.

I'd like to show all slides in a same view and it loop like a circular.
[image]

This is initial slides. Center slide is third slide. And If I click next button or swipe slider to next, I expect to show slider like below. Center slide is 4th slide and then 1st slide move to the last. But slider duplicate lots of slides and it loops in a one direction not circular. I've tried parameters according to loop. But It doesn't work what I expected.

[image]

Is there any way to work with Swiper Api?

Answer (score 0):

Loop mode was completly reworked in version 9 of Swiper and what you are trying achieve is no longer possible. If you want to make it work, you should unfortunetaly downgrade to version 8.

After downgrade its pretty stright forward, please see code snipplet.

However if you are using wersion <9 then please share your code, so we could help.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        loop: true,
      slidesPerView: 5,
      spaceBetween: 30,
      pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true,
      },
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

  <!-- Demo styles -->
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .swiper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .swiper-slide img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```